# using generic createapiview and updateapiview in the same view in django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

Iam trying to find out if it is possible to post and patch in the same view using the generic api method in Django rest framework. I dont think there is any generic class that allows create and update altogether, can anyone tell me if the below configuration would allow me to use post and patch method in the same view.

```
class QuestionList(generics.updateAPIView, generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is possible but, You can create two views like this

```
class CreateSomeView(AuthenticatedView, CreateAPIView):

    queryset = Some.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

 class SomeView(AuthenticatedView, UpdateAPIView):

    queryset = Some.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
```

and two urls something like that

```
path('some/', CreateSomeView.as_view(), name="create-some-details"),
path('some/<int:pk>/', SomeView.as_view(), name="some-details"),
```

Now, from front-end you can send request with  if you want to update or without id if you wish to create new. You don't have to create two serializers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use them at the same time,you can create a custom view that inherits from both classes

```
from rest_framework import generics

class MyView(generics.CreateAPIView, generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

and in you urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('myview/', MyView.as_view(), name='myview'),
path('myview/<int:pk>/', MyView.as_view(), name='myview_update'),]
```

if you want to use your uuid or an identifier you have to add to your views:

```
    lookup_field = "uuid"
```

and change

```
    path('myview/<uuid:uuid>/', MyView.as_view(), name='myview_update'),
```

Comment: that's so bad i'd split them into two classes so u can edit each one seperatly